# Anybody knows how to make the JSon suggest close on click?

Tags: jquery, json, plugins, suggestbox

i'm using this [json suggest box](https://github.com/cootetom/jQuery-JSON-Suggest-Search-Box)

and i was wondering if there's a way to include an option to make it close when the user click on somewhere else?

else right now unless the user select something, the suggest box will never close.

Or is there another suggest box out there that i can use? basically my data are in json format.

sorry if this question sounds lazy, but i think if there's other json suggest users, they might appreciate this too.

### Updates:

One of my senior developer came up with this: :)

```
$(document).click(function() {
        $(".jsonSuggestResults").hide();
    });
```

Comment: In the link you provided the box closes when you click outside of it.

Comment: +1 for Darin. Box closes when you click outside of it. So either rephrase or specify in which broswer / under what circumstances this doesn't work

Comment: mm, weird, must be a combination of stuff that i'm using which is causing this..

Answer (score -1):

don't know your primary problem because it's working on the link givin but if you are looking for something similar, try [jqueryui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)